# Gaussian elimination code

Tags: c++, matrix

I have tried to write code that reads in values from an nxn matrix and then print those values out. I think I have succeeded in doing this. The next step I have tried is to solve the matrix using Gaussian elimination but I can't get the code to print out the values. Could someone please have a look at this and tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <cmath>
  #include <vector>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <string>

  using namespace std;


   int main(){
   //create a 2D vector of doubles 
   vector< vector< double > > matrix; 


    int num_lines = 0;
    double temporary, r;
    int i, j, k, dimension, temp; /* counter variables for loops */




    // Open a file containing the matrix data
    ifstream myFile("test_data2.txt");
    // Check if file is open
    if(myFile.is_open()){
    // First step is to detect matrix size by assuming matrix is
    // square and counting number of columns.

    // Tempoary variable to hold current line to process
    string line;

    // Tempoary variable to hold number of rows and cols in square matrix
    int num_lines = 0;

    // Count rows / cols
    while(getline(myFile, line)){
        num_lines ++;
    }

    // Reset EOF flag
    myFile.clear();

    // Reset to start of file
    myFile.seekg(0, myFile.beg);

    // Second step is to grab lines from the file and process them
    // splitting each line into substrings and converting them into
    // doubles

    // For each line
    for(int l = 0; l < num_lines; l ++){
        // Process line by line
        getline(myFile, line);

        // Tempoary vector to hold rows of matrix data
        vector<double> temp;

        // Tempoary variable to hold search positions
        int start = 0;
        int end;
        int length;

        // Get value by value
        for(int n = 0; n < num_lines; n ++){
            // Break line down by finding commas
            end = line.find(',', start);
            length = end - start;

            // Extract substring
            string tempstr = line.substr(start, length);

            // Set next value of start
            start = end + 1;

            // Convert to double
            temp.push_back(atof(tempstr.c_str()));
        }

        // Add row to matrix
        matrix.push_back(temp);
    }
    // Close input file
    myFile.close();
} else {
    // If input file failed to open, print an error
    cout << "Error opening input file" << endl;
}
// Print out the matrix (will do nothing if input file open failed)
cout << "Print out input file." << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i ++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j ++)
    {
        cout << matrix[i][j];
        // Add commas and new lines when required
        // Remember not to add commas after rightmost values, or
        // a new line at the end of the last value
        if(j < matrix[i].size() - 1)
        {
            cout << ' '; // Character, not string
        }
        else
        {
            if(i < matrix[i].size() - 1)
            {
                cout << '\n'; // Character, not string
            }
        }
    }
}






 for (i = 0; i < num_lines; i++)
    for (j = num_lines; j < 2 * num_lines; j++)
        if (i == j % num_lines)
            matrix[i][j] = 1;
        else
            matrix[i][j] = 0;

  /* using gauss-jordan elimination */
  for (j = 0; j < num_lines; j++) {
    temp = j;

    /* finding maximum jth column element in last (dimension-j) rows */
    for (i = j + 1; i < num_lines; i++)
        if (matrix[i][j] > matrix[temp][j])
            temp = i;



    /* swapping row which has maximum jth column element */
    if (temp != j)
        for (k = 0; k < 2 * num_lines; k++) {
            temporary = matrix[j][k];
            matrix[j][k] = matrix[temp][k];
            matrix[temp][k] = temporary;
        }

      /* performing row operations to form required identity matrix out of the input              matrix */
    for (i = 0; i < num_lines; i++)
        if (i != j) {
            r = matrix[i][j];
            for (k = 0; k < 2 * num_lines; k++)
                matrix[i][k] -= matrix[j][k] * r / matrix[j][j];
        } else {
            r = matrix[i][j];
            for (k = 0; k < 2 * dimension; k++)
                matrix[i][k] /= r;
        }
   }

   /* Display augmented matrix */
   printf("\n After Gauss-Jordan elimination, augmented matrix is : \n\n");

  for (i = 0; i < num_lines; i++) {
     for (j = 0; j < 2 * num_lines; j++)
        printf("  %4.2f", matrix[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
   }


   /* displaying inverse of the non-singular matrix */
   printf("\n\n\n The inverse of the entered non-singular matrix is : \n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < num_lines; i++) {
    for (j = num_lines; j < 2 * num_lines; j++)
        printf("  %.5f", matrix[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }


 return 0;
  }

    // EXAMPLE FILE
    //1,2,3
    //4.5,6.7,8.8
    //-110,-55.3,+53.723
    // END OF EXAMPLE FILE REMOVE COMMENTS AT TOP AND BOTTOM AND "//" characters before    use. Save as "matrix.csv".
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Stacktrace / output?

Comment: It will print out the read in matrix but then just blank space where I'd hoped the other values would be

Comment: does your program terminate? or does it just keep running?

Comment: it terminates, it writes out the statements but not the values

Comment: Ok. now you know that you're not getting stuck in an infinite loop (most cases). Now you need to step through your code and see how the variables change as the code runs. Debug the code. walk through it step by step and see exactly what's happening to your variables or exactly what happens when you try to print them

Answer (score 1):

BUG1:

You declare the

```
 int num_lines = 0;
```

inside the

```
 if(myFile.is_open())
```

block. Thus, the 'num_lines++' line increments this variable in the

```
 while(getline(....) )
```

loop, but then num_lines( the second one) gets undeclared and all the loops (gaussian elimination and printing) just iterate zero times.

Remove the second num_lines declaration.

BUG 2:

The 'dimension' variable is never initialized. Logically, it shoud be equal to 'num_lines'.

BUG 3:

The 'matrix' variable does not get initialized correctly. You push_back the 'temp' vector there, but is has only the 'num_lines' length, not the 'num_lines * 2'.

PS: I cannot guarantee there are no more bugs.